# Double for loop, storing created variables in a list

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

I've been trying to use a double for loop to create simple character vectors and saving them in a list:

```
exercise <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  for (k in 1:3) {
    exercise[?] <- paste("AR", i , "MA", k)
  }
}
```

the output should be:

```
[[1]]
[1] "AR 1 MA 1"

[[2]]
[1] "AR 1 MA 2"

[[3]]
[1] "AR 1 MA 3"

[[4]]
[1] "AR 2 MA 1"

[[5]]
[1] "AR 2 MA 2"
etc...
```

The whole list should then have 9 character objects, but I just cannot figure out how to efficiently save them in the desired order. This has to have a simple answer, however I have not found any solution to this as of yet. Later, I want to store ARIMA(p,q) models in the list instead of just character vectors, but the system should be the same.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `as.list(outer(1:3, 1:3, FUN = function(x, y) paste("AR", x, "MA", y)))`

Comment: funny one `paste0("AR ", 1:3, " MA ", rep(1:3, 3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the double for loop, you can do the following:

```
for(i in 1:3){
    for (k in 1:3) {
        exercise[length(exercise) + 1] <- paste("AR", i , "MA", k)
    }
}
```

With `exercise[length(exercise) + 1]`, we update the last element of `exercise` at each iteration.